# Http-Duplicate data gets uploaded to the server

Tags: android

I had developed an android application which syncs data to the server using http connection
but unfortunately, duplicate data get submitted to the server and also sometimes truncated data being passed to the server.

Please help me if any one has the solution for my issue

I am using following code

```
{
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
    if (!(urlConn instanceof HttpURLConnection)) {
        throw new IOException ("URL is not an Http URL");
    }
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)urlConn;
    httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + 
    Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
    httpConn.setConnectTimeout(1000);
    httpConn.connect(); 
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
    httpConn.getOutputStream ());
    wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
    wr.flush ();
    wr.close ();
    resCode = httpConn.getResponseCode(); 
    if (resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        in = httpConn.getInputStream();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the above code. because this looks correct

Comment: It is strange data is duplicated. Can you post how you create urlParameters? If you try to call the server side using a simple html page is the data still duplicated?